# Set Theory Proof Involving Complements

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I just got started with proofs and set theory concepts, and I just wanted to check my understanding by completing a proof on my own using the definition of a subset. So, I was just wondering if this proof makes sense and is a valid proof.

### Here is the question:

Let A, B be two arbitrary sets. Prove that if $$B^c ⊆ A^c,$$ then $$A ⊆ B $$

### Here is my proof:

If $X ∈ A,$ then $X ∉ A^c$ which => $X ∉ B^c$ since $B^c ⊆ A^c$ is given. If $X ∉ A^c$ and $X ∉ B^c$, then, it implies that $X ∈ B$. Since $X ∈ A$ and $X ∈ B$ that means $ A ⊆ B$ which proves the statement.

Thanks!

Comment: What do $S$ and $T$ have to do with $A$ and $B$?

Comment: I am really sorry, it's supposed to be A and B, not S and T.

Comment: Except … that will not be provable.  You surely want to prove $B\subseteq A$ is a consequence of $A^\complement\subseteq B^\complement$.  See below, and consider the hint: use contraposition.

Comment: My apologies! I messed the order of the sets when I wrote this post. Got a little excited after I thought I proved this statement..

Answer (score 1):

> If $X ∈ A,$ then $X ∉ A^c$ which => $X ∉ B^c$, ...

Nope.  Let $A^\complement=\{1\}$ and $B^\complement=\{1,2\}$ so that we do have $A^\complement\subseteq B^\complement$.

Well now, $2\in A$, so $2\notin A^\complement$, yet $2\in B^\complement$ and thus $2\notin B$, so $A\nsubseteq B$.

> ... then if $X ∉ A^c$ and $X ∉ B^c$, then, it implies that $X ∈ B$. Since $X ∈ A$ and $X ∈ B$ that means $ A ⊆ B$ which proves the statement.

It does not, and should not.    $A\subseteq B$ is *not* a logical consequence of $A^\complement\subseteq B^\complement$.

---

Try proving that if $A^\complement\subseteq B^\complement$ then $B\subseteq A$.

Comment: Note: $P\to Q$ if and only if $\neg Q\to\neg P$.  (Contraposition)

Comment: Will now the proof be valid? (I changed the order of the sets as I realized it was not in the right order in the first place).

Comment: It needs a *bit* more work., @Abwatts.  Think about it a bit more, and try again.  It is basically a proof by contradiction. $$\text{When given $B^\complement \subseteq A^\complement$, then for any $x\in A$, if we assume $x\in B^\complement$, then ...}$$

Comment: I understand. I have never proved a proof by contradiction, so I tried to solve it by direct proving it. Will proving this statement using a direct proof be significantly harder than proving it by contradiction?